# Swap 2 number in tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a pair of `Variable` `i` and `j` and a `Tensor` `A`, how to get a new `Tensor` which is `A` with `i`th element and `j`th element swapped? How about `N` pairs of `i` and `j` and we need to swap them all? How to do that in batch training?

I found swapping one pair is easy:

```
if i < j:
    return tf.concat((A[:i], A[j], A[i+1:j], A[i], A[j+1:]), 0)
else:
    return tf.concat((A[:j], A[i], A[j+1:i], A[j], A[i+1:]), 0)
```

Swapping multiple pairs would require explicit loop / reducing:

```
for i, j in ijpairs:
    A = swap_one_pair(A, i, j)
return A
```

Swapping multiple samples in a batch would require explicit mapping:

```
return tf.map_fn(swap_one_pair, (As, is, js))
```

I found if I separate the swapping into "read" and "write", reading can be easily vectorized via `gather_nd`:

```
indexes = tf.stack((tf.tile(tf.range(batch_size)[:,None], (1,read_size)), all_i), 2)
index_results = tf.gather_nd(A, indexes)
```

Is there a "write" version of `gather_nd`? Or is there any more elegant way of implementing swapping utilizing vectorization/broadcasting?

**EDIT**

I found a "write" version `scatter_nd_update`. Unfortunately it only works for `Variable`. I tried casting `Tensor` to `Variable` using `tf.Variable(myTensor)` but don't work. I currently use:

```
def scatter_nd_update(ref, indices, updates):
    original_part = ref * (1 - tf.scatter_nd(indices, tf.ones(updates.shape), ref.shape))
    update_part   = tf.scatter_nd(index, update, ref.shape)
    return original_part + update_part
```

This method uses a lot of meaningless computation. Any idea of better one?